# Convert an in-ordered and pre-ordered array to a BST

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, tree

I am working on a Daily Coding Challenge to print the BST if given an in-ordered and pre-ordered array.

Below is my code in JavaScript ES6.

Please can you review it. This is my first fully-featured JS program so I am very unaware of standard syntax or shortcuts in JS

```
function Tree(){
    this.value = null 
    this.right = null 
    this.left = null
    this.reconstruct = (pre_order, in_order)=>{
        if (pre_order){
            if (this.value == null){
                this.value = pre_order[0]
            }
            let node = pre_order[0]
            let split_index = in_order.indexOf(node)
            let left_tree = in_order.slice(0, split_index)
            let right_tree = in_order.slice(split_index+1)

            this.left = new Tree()
            this.right = new Tree()

            if (left_tree.length>1){
                this.left.reconstruct(pre_order.slice(1, split_index), left_tree)
            }else{
                if (left_tree){
                    this.left.value = left_tree[0]
                }
            }
            if (right_tree.length>1){
                this.right.reconstruct(pre_order.slice(split_index+1), right_tree)
            }else{
                if (right_tree){
                    this.right.value = right_tree[0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this.print_tree = (level) =>{
        if (this.value){
            console.log(" ".repeat(level), this.value)
            if(this.left){
                this.left.print_tree(level+1)
            }
            if(this.right){
                this.right.print_tree(level+1)
            }
        }
    }
}
in_order = [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 12, 8, 13, 7, 10, 9, 11]
pre_order = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11]
t = new Tree()
t.reconstruct(pre_order, in_order)
t.print_tree(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few key points:

- Make sure to put in semicolons!
- You don't need to export properties (i.e do `this.myVar`) if you're not going to access them - this can lead to potentially slowing down recurrence, or in some cases, security vulnerabilities.
- If you're going to use arrow functions, keep it consistent - do `const Tree = () => {` on the first line

Some more specific things about the actual functionality/logic:

- By tracking `this.level`, you could simplify all required actions into an array by simply pushing their position in the tree. If `this.level === 0`, you know you are at the top of the tree, and you know to end recurrence.
- Using a position-based tracking lets you make it asyncronous, and print the result at the end. Remember that in JS, `console.log`s take a lot of time, so you want to avoid it as much as possible.
- This would let you essentially JSONify the tree into a bunch of function references, which, when called, would populate themselves. Giving the option to return this would make the class more integratable into other things, where a console output is not necessarily the most useful thing. Further, it would let you cut out the repetition of `if (left_tree.length>1){`, which is not DRY.